# Confusion of a Claim in Talagrand's Paper

Tags: matrices, inequality, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

In one of Talagrand's [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220050108) on isoperimetric inequalities, it says

> "... Consider independent Bernoulli random variables ($P(\epsilon_i = 1) = P(\epsilon_i = -1) = 1/2$) and vectors $(x_{ij})_{i,j\leq n}$ is a Banach space $W$. We assume $x_{ii} = 0$ for all $i \leq n$, and that $x_{ij} = x_{ji}$. We denote by $W_1^*$ the unit ball of $W$, and consider the numbers
>   $$
> U = \sup\left\{\sum_{i,j\leq n} \alpha_i \beta_j x^* (x_{ij});\ x^* \in W_1^*, \sum_{i\leq n}\alpha_i^2 = 1, \sum_{j \leq n}\beta_j^2 = 1\right\}
> $$
>   Thus $U$ is the supremum of the operator norms of the matrices $(x^*(x_{ij}))_{i, j}$. ..."

I am confused on the last sentence about $U$. Observe $U$ is obtained by taking supremum on a set of matrices by definition, since $x^*$ is a matrix. How can it be a number? Am I missing something?

Comment: Read the definition of $U$ carefully. It is the supremum of a collection of numbers so it is a number. For example if you take the supremum of the traces of a collection of matrices do you get a number or a matrix?. Instead of concentrarting on 'Supremum over what'  concentrate on 'supremum of what'.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So $x^*$ here is actually a function?

Comment: Yes, $x^{*}$ is a function defined on $W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^*$ is in $W_1^*$ so doesn't denote a matrix, it denotes a linear functional $x^*:W\to \mathbb R.$ The notation $(x^*(x_{ij}))_{i,j}$ does denote a matrix - it's $x^*$ applied entrywise. For each fixed $x^*,$ the quantity

$$
\sup\left\{\sum_{i,j\leq n} \alpha_i \beta_j x^*(x_{ij}); \sum_{i\leq n}\alpha_i^2 = 1, \sum_{j \leq n}\beta_j^2 = 1\right\}
$$

is the $\ell_2$ operator norm (aka spectral norm) of the matrix $(x^*(x_{ij}))_{i,j}.$ Taking the supremum over $x^*\in W_1^*$ gives $U.$

Comment: $W_1^*$ is defined to be the unit ball of $W$, so I originally thought it is a set. Could you please give $W_1^*$'s mathematical definition?

Comment: @xuhafiz: I'm pretty sure that's a typo in Talagrand's paper. $W^*_1$ is the unit ball in the dual space: the set of functionals $W\to\mathbb R$ of norm at most $1.$ The unit ball in $W$ would just be denoted $W_1.$